# Refrigerated Beef Brisket

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, beef

I bought some prime trimmed beef brisket on March 9 with a sell by date of Mar. 12. It was kept in the frig in its foam/plastic wrap container until Mar.16. There was some odor when I opened it up and put it up to my nose. I washed it off and cut away some meat and scraped it off. Not much odor anymore. It had reached room temp for a short period of time before I did this and then I wrapped it and froze it.

Is it likely safe to eat? No children or immune compromised people will eat it and it will be thoroughly cooked first.

Answer (score 0):

Throw it away. It could be safe, especially if you thoroughly cook it as that will kill any parasites and break down any toxins present. However, even if may not hurt you it's probably going to taste pretty awful.